# How can one put the output of a command into a konsole title bar?

Tags: linux, kde-plasma, konsole

Through the clever use of some escape characters, I used to put the output of arbitrary commands (e.g. "dirs") into my xterm title bar.  Can I do the same thing in konsole?  If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a little tricky to do what you want, but **you can change** Konsole's title bar. Go to:

`Settings > Edit current profile > Tabs > Tab title format`

and change it to `%w` which means *Window Title Set by Shell*. I think you need to close Konsole and reopen it for the changes to take effect.

Anyway, go to the prompt and exec:

```
OUTPUT=`whoami`; echo -ne "\033]2;$OUTPUT\007"
```

and behold!

This example sets the title of the window **temporarily** to whatever is outputted by *whoami*.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it using dbus:

```
qdbus $KONSOLE_DBUS_SERVICE $KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION setTitle 1 $(dirs)
```

for KDE 3, using dcop:

```
dcop $KONSOLE_DCOP_SESSION renameSession $(dirs)
```